# How to replace all percent-encoded UTF-8 substrings with plain UTF-8 text?

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding, text, unicode

I've got a html file with a lot of %-encoded UTF-8 text in URLs.

For example "%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B" stands for "ресурсы" ("resources" in Russian).

The task is to replace all such substrings with readable UTF-8 text.

To simplify the task we can consider there is no other `%` sign usage in the file. Letter digits can be both upper and lower case.

I suspect this can be done elegantly with `sed`, `perl`, `awk` or something but don't know how.

[This web application](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) seems to do the trick with text you paste there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With bash, zsh, GNU echo or some implementations of ksh on some systems, this can be decoded simply by `echo -e` after replacing all `%` with `\x`.

```
url_encoded_string="%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B"
temp_string=${url_encoded_string//%/\\x}

printf '%s\n' "$temp_string"
# output: \xD1\x80\xD0\xB5\xD1\x81\xD1\x83\xD1\x80\xD1\x81\xD1\x8B

echo -e "$temp_string"
# output: ресурсы
```

(It assumes the string itself doesn't contain backslash characters and is not one of the options supported by your `echo` command)

As @JoshLee also points out, the "echo caveat" can be avoided by directly using:

```
printf ${url_encoded_string//%/\\x}
```

instead directly behind the first command.

Comment: Note that this elegant solution will work with _any_ encoding, not just UTF-8 (i.e., get rid of the encodings for ~ and others. Another trick to add to my toolbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

With perl:

```
perl -pe 's/%([0-9A-F]{2})/pack"H2",$1/gei'
```

Or with `URI::Escape`:

```
perl -MURI::Escape -pe '$_=uri_unescape$_'
```

Comment: I love this because I can pipe it whatever I want thanks to `$_` https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html

Comment: @Nemo, `$_` here is `perl`'s `$_`, not `bash`'s. In combination with the `-p` option, the perl expression is run for every input record (records being read from files given as argument or stdin if no argument is provided), with the current record stored in `$_`. That's similar  to `awk`'s `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called `convmv` which can help you.

Simply use `convmv --unescape /some_path/target_file`. It will do a dry-run.

Once you have confirmed, use `convmv --notest --unescape /some_path/target_file` to continue.

The homepage of this program is: http://j3e.de/linux/convmv/